# Operator '==' cannot be applied to types knockoutObservable<string> and string

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

When I try to use a condition inside if in typescript I'm getting the error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to types knockoutObservable and string "

if(me.Info().roomName == "-")
{

}

I'm getting the intellisense error in VS2013 for this statement. Please advice.

Comment: What do you don't understand about the error?

Comment: Do I need to convert the "-" into any other type like ko.observable("-"). I just need to check whether the observable string is "-" or not. I tried different ways and still it's showing error. I tried me.Info().roomName() and other options. It tells roomName() is not a function. In this roomName is KnockoutObservable<string>.

Comment: I tried converting both the values to knockout observable string like this.    this.Info().roomName == ko.observable<string>("-"). Still it doesn't work as expected. Even if the roomName is "-" the condition returns false.

Comment: Both are different type of objects that is why you are getting the error. Is roomName a string or of different type? When you are converting '-' to same type as roomName what is the error? Please post the code for RoomName

Comment: export class BInfo {    
        
        roomName: KnockoutObservable<string>;}  Below is how Info observableCollection is declared in ViewModel.                Info: KnockoutObservable<BInfo> = ko.observable(null);

Comment: I didn't get any error. But still the condition was always returning false even if the condition is true

Comment: Please post all the code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call your observable to get its value so that you can compare it to a string:

```
if(me.Info().roomName() == "-") {

}
```